# Xamarin.Essentials Never Prompts For Permissions

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to use `Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps` with location services on a **Android** project. My problem is the app never prompts me for the location permissions. My *MainActivity.cs* page looks like this

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.FormsGoogleMaps.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

I have the permissions listed in my Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

But when i try and uses `Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps` and set `MyLocationEnabled="True"`

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="2">
    <maps:Map VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" MyLocationEnabled="True"> 
    </maps:Map>
</StackLayout>
```

I get the following error

> Java.Lang.SecurityException: 'my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or 
>   ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'

The app never asks me to grant permissions which i thought the `OnRequestPermissionsResult` was suppose to handle. I must be missing something. Do I have to manually ask for the permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not something that is performed automatically by the Android OS. You need to manually request permission when you're about to use something that requires permission. In your case Location permissions. The easiest way to do this is to use the permissions plugin [Plugin.Permissions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Permissions).

You'll also need to handle the response from the user because if you try to use the permission anyways after they've denied it your app will crash.

Answer (score 1):

You don't miss anything regarding whether it works or not.

Just you miss that there is no way that one plugin can know that you are installing and using another plugin that will require permission for location. Those permissions need to be requested at a run-time in specific places in the app and have to be handled either by the plugin that requires the permission (which will be activated at that point and can do the check if it was programmed to do so) or by yourself.